# how to use cgroup_conf in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

i want to limit Memory & CPU usage a docker container can consume by
`ENV CGROUP_CONF memory:75%;cpu:10%` 
inside the container runs a nodejs api with a docker file like so:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV CGROUP_CONF memory:75%;cpu:10% 

RUN npm install
RUN .........

COPY . .    
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node","--experimental-specifier-resolution", "node", "--loader", "ts-node/esm", "src/app.ts" ]
```

but somehow the cgroup thing does not work.
Where is the Problem? is the host machine (debian 11) not supporting it? or the node:alpine-16 source?

Thanks a lot for clarification what the Problem could be ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such variable `CGROUP_CONF`. cgroups does not know it.

Normally you leave it up to the operator what resources they want to give the container. Docker has [runtime options](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) for this.

```
docker run --memory 256Mi --cpus 2
```